# Unexpected token error when POSTing to Shopify's Billing API

Tags: jquery, shopify

I'm developing a Shopify's rails app. In **development** mode I'm trying to create a new recurring application charge with [Shopify's Billing API](http://docs.shopify.com/api/recurringapplicationcharge#create) by making this POST request from my *index.html.erb*:

```
(function($) {

  var url = 'https://test.myshopify.com/admin/recurring_application_charges.json?';

  $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
      url: url,
      crossDomain: true,
      async: false,
      contentType: "application/json",
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      data: {"recurring_application_charge": {"name": "Super Duper Plan", "test" :     "true", "price": 10.0, "return_url": "http://super-duper.shopifyapps.com", "trial_days": 5}},
      jsonp: 'whatever',
      success: function(json) {
        alert("success " + json);
      },
      error: function(e) {
         console.log(e.message);
      }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

I get the following error in my browser's console:

```
   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : https://test.myshopify.com/admin/recurring_application_charges.json?whatever=jQuery1102022113484237343073_1393499741382&{%22recurring_application_charge%22:%20{%22name%22:%20%22Super%20Duper%20Plan%22,%20%22test%22%20:%20%22true%22,%20%22price%22:%2010.0,%20%22return_url%22:%20%22http://super-duper.shopifyapps.com%22,%20%22trial_days%22:%205%20}&_=1393499741383
```

and when I click on the error link it takes me to a page showing

```
  {"recurring_application_charges":[]}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get access to the Shopify API you should specify:

- a `X-Shopify-Access-Token` within the header of your request
- *or* specify `apikey:password` within the URL your trying to access. For example `https://apikey:password@hostname/admin/resource.json`

However both the `X-Shopify-Access-Token` and `apikey` `password` combination **should be kept secret**. So you shouldn't include those secrets into a public readable code (`js` or `html`). Those actions typically should be initiated from within a controller.

For example you could create a `ChargeController` which calls the `ShopifyAPI::RecurringCharge` method:

```
class ChargeController < ApplicationController
  around_filter :shopify_session

  # create new RecurringApplicationCharge
  def create
    ShopifyAPI::Base.activate_session(...)
    ShopifyAPI::RecurringApplicationCharge.create(
      name: "Super Duper Plan",
      price: 10.0,
      test: !Rails.env.production?,
      return_url: charge_activate_url,
      trial_days: 5
    )
  end

  # activate RecurringApplicationCharge
  def update
    ShopifyAPI::Base.activate_session(...)
    ShopifyAPI::RecurringApplicationCharge.find(params[:charge_id])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the ' after *data* and adding the missing }.

Which gives you:

```
(function($) {
  var url = 'https://test.myshopify.com/admin/recurring_application_charges.json?';

  $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
      url: url,
      crossDomain: true,
      async: false,
      contentType: "application/json",
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      data: {"recurring_application_charge": {"name": "Super Duper Plan", "test" :     "true", "price": 10.0, "return_url": "http://super-duper.shopifyapps.com", "trial_days": 5     }
      },
      jsonp: 'whatever',
      success: function(json) {
      alert("success " + json);
  },
  error: function(e) {
     console.log(e.message);
  }
 });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I'll update the question accordingly. Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the problem. I still get the same error.

Comment: Do you?
I get an authorization window when I try it.

Comment: When I use my development shop example, not test.myshopify.com, is when I get the error. See http://jsfiddle.net/Mike238748/Kh7P2/